# nlapiResolveURL, identifiers?

Tags: netsuite

I'm having trouble finding the identifiers for the nlapiResolveURL command. According to the dev guide, `nlapiResolveURL(type, identifier, id, displayMode)` and identifier is `identifier {string} [required] - The primary id for this resource (recordType for RECORD, scriptId for SUITELET)`

for bill payments the recordType is `vendorpayment` not VendPymt I have been searching in the dev guide for the list of recordTypes but I can seem to find the list of recordTypes to use for nlapiResolveURL

Comment: I believe I may have found the list, I believe its the supported transaction types --direct void. on page 452 on the dev guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check SuiteScript Supported Records to check the internal id's of records that is to be used in identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Records Browser for a list of all Records. The page for each Record Type will display its Internal ID, which is always in all lowercase letters (e.g. "salesorder", "invoice", "journalentry").

In addition to that, when you are running SuiteScript in the context of a record (e.g. User Event or Client Script), you can use `nlapiGetRecordType()` to get the type's internal ID.

*Edit*: Just found the page title *SuiteScript Supported Records* in the NetSuite Help. This has a list of all record types supported by SuiteScript along with their internal IDs. There is an accompanying *Web Services Supported Records* if you're using the SOAP API as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bookmark on your browser and paste this as the link

```
javascript:if(nsRecordTypes==null){nsRecordTypes=nsServerCall(nsJSONProxyURL,"getRecordTypes");};console.log("nsRecordTypes");console.log(nsRecordTypes)
```

Then go to NetSuite and open the console (F12 in Chrome > console), and press the bookmark button.

This will show all record types in NetSuite.